# I see no check box to the left of an answer on my question

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I asked my first question today and received 2 good answers. The faq says:

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

I cannot see a "check box outline to the left of the answer". I appreciate the answers and want to indicate my acceptance, but can't. How can I fix this?

Using Firefox 4 on Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question? I don't see it; you have one question here (this one) and none on SO

Comment: The account you used here links to an account on SO with no questions or answers, so it's highly likely that you created a duplicate account on SO. If you logged in with your duplicate account, you're not going to see check box outlines in the question you posted *because you are not the OP.* Can you provide a link to the question so I can merge your two accounts?

Comment: Correct.  When I asked the question I was unregistered.  When I didn't see the check mark I assumed it was because I was not registered and did so.  It is fixed now and I was able to accept an answer.  Thanks for your help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @RobertHarvey said, you had two accounts--one registered, and one unregistered.

I've merged the unregistered one into your registered account... ***with my mind.***

https://stackoverflow.com/users/810838/cleanman2

Comment: How did you find the other one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: **with his mind.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It takes a **[MAN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-cl/83752#83752)** to find cookie based accounts with the same email address as a registered account.

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue here might stem from how the FAQ says "check box outline" when it should *actually* say "check **mark** outline".

Do you see a faint checkmark-like shape on the left (it should be right underneath the number showing the votes on that answer), or is that not visible? Below is an image of how it would look on Stack Overflow.
← On this post on Meta, it should be located right about here, assuming normal zoom and no other browser specialities.

[image: Hastily retrieved image of a check mark outline]